# How to change module name in joomla Module Manager

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-module

[image: Module name in Joomla Module Manager]

How can I change the name of the joomla module in joomla module manager, when showing module properties. How to change the name with red underline in picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I was looking for the same answer of this problem. I found out it needs some language files to show the module name.

I've downloaded a simple login register module from: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/15380 and followed it's file tree structure and looked into its xml file. See this image:

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ismRln97BJg/UEYAwPKF7RI/AAAAAAAAAEE/J7eBX5N0taw/s800/joomla-module-name.png]

Comment: So you want to say that it might be in sys.ini ?? I'll check it out today)

Comment: Actually it is in these language ini files. But I'm not sure exactly which one is needed for this. I used all four of them. The module name is in first line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit mod_b2j_k2_news_slider.xml, change the name.

Comment: Can u exactly tell where I need to change the name ?